# Parse:Swift: getDataInBackground, but data doesn't exist

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I have a problem with parse. I was trying to save profile pics for my users, which worked perfectly. Then I wanted to show the profile pic inside an image view, if the user looks at his own profile. Problem is that when a user hasn't set an profile pic before, it lets my app crash, because there is no data to find when it tries to do the getDataInBackgroundWithBlock function. How can I solve this? Here is my code that should display the corresponding profile pic inside the profilePicImageView. I tried it without the else statement before, same problem :/

```
let profileImage = currentUser?.objectForKey("profilePic") as? PFFile

            profileImage!.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock({ (imageData:NSData?, error:NSError?) -> Void in

                if (error == nil){
                    let image:UIImage = UIImage(data: imageData!)!
                    self.profilePicImageView.image = image
                }else {

                    self.profilePicImageView.image = nil

                }

            })
```

Comment: Just check if 'imageData' is nil.

Comment: Do you see those ! in the `UIImage(data:imageData!)!` - they say "these things won't be nil and if they are then the app should crash".  You need to check the optionals for nil.  Have you read the Swift book in iBooks? Optionals are explained pretty clearly there.

Comment: Sorry I'm actually very new to programming, I knew about optionals and tried it without the !, but xCode forced me to make them. But thanks to your answer I tried profileImage?.getDataInBackground(...) instead of the ! and now it works perfectly! So it wasn't because of the forced unwrapping of imageData which you thought, but of profileImage... thanks for you help though :) ps: I read some of the swift books but I prefer learning by doing :P

Answer (score 0):

ParseUI has a class named PFImageView, which is a subclass of UIImageView. Instead of using UIImageView, you can do something like:
1. Set the class to PFImageView in Interface Builder
2. Make an outlet to that PFImageView to profilePicImageView
3. Change your code to:

```
self.profilePicImageView,image = <Any placeholder>
if let profileImage = currentUser?.objectForKey("profilePic") as? PFFile {
   self.profilePicImageView.file = profileImage
   self.profilePicImageView.loadInBackground()
}
```